# Css div styling

Tags: html, css

I have one div, it contains two divs inside it, I'm including the source code below, question is: if I zoom out in the firefox, chrome  from theses divs second div flows out from it's place and stands below the first div, how should I write css in order it stayed in it's place?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="id1"></div>
    <div id="id2"></div>
</div>
```

Style.css is

```
#container {
    width: 646px;
    height: auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}

 #id1 {
    float: left;
    width: 315px;
    height: 115px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #cccccc;
}

 #id2 {
    float: left;
    width: 314px;
    height: 115px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #cccccc;
    margin-left:13px;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to increase the `#container` width.

Comment: why to increase the width, for let's calculate: #container width equals to 646px, #id width is 315px, border right and left 2px, #id width is 314px border right and left 2px and margi-left 13px, so let's summarize them 315px+2px+314px+2px+13px = 646px, am I right? or am i missing smth else?

Comment: please @micha write my nick correctly, it's not Dubalizer but Drupalizer ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because if you zoom out the will decrease the size of the element on the screen. But because the border is so small they can't decrease the size of it anymore, so it will stay the same.

If you really want to fix it you should increase the width of `#container` to about `652px`.